# What is the word for the double vowel in "coordinate"?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, vowels, diphthongs

The word **coordinate** has two vowels in it, that would ordinarily make the /u/ sound. Probably because of the word's etymology (Latin co- ‎(“together”) + ordinare ‎(“arrange”)) it is not pronounced as such but as two separate sounds.

Usually, the word for a pair of vowels would be a *[diphthong](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diphthong)* or a *[digraph](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digraph)*, however, those words are reserved specifically for two vowels which make **one** syllable.

> Two vowel sounds joined in one syllable to form one speech sound

([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diphthong))

Is there a specific linguistic term for a pair of vowels that, when pronounced, for **two** speech sounds?

Comment: I note that in the UK they often write *coördinate, naïve*, and so on to show ths type of pronunciation.

Comment: @GEdgar Your bang on! I hadn't seen this before, but, as my answer details, it is used to differentiate between a diphthong and a diæresis.

Comment: @GEdgar We don't often use a diaeresis, actually, and certainly vanishingly seldom on a letter other than *i*.

Comment: @AndreLeach, yes the only times I can think of seeing it recently is on *naïve*

Comment: Are you looking for the term for when two adjacent vowels occupy separate syllables because they’re in hiatus?

Comment: @tchrist, yes, if you think that diæreses and their ommission doesn't cover it

Comment: (The *New Yorker* magazine always uses diaeresis and similar.)

Comment: @Bladorthin As I'm told the English say, I haven't the foggiest what "Your bang on!'" means. For those of us who live on the other side of the Atlantic Pond, would you translate your statement into our native tongue?

Comment: @Airymouse "Exactly correct" ([Merriam-Webser](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bang%20on)) E.g. Merriam-Webster's definition is *bang on*!

Comment: @Airymouse It was a typo, should have been “you're bang on”, ‘bang’ being an intensifier here like ‘right on [the money]’.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I completely missed that. Oops! So much for English Language and Usage!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adjacent vowels that are pronounced as separate syllables are said to be in [*hiatus*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hiatus):

> A break between two vowels coming together but not in the same syllable, as in the ear and cooperate. (Oxford Dictionaries)

However, I don't know of any specific terms for the vowels themselves, or for the sequence of vowel letters.

Answer (score 1):

It appears I may have come to EL&U to hastily; the [Wiktionary page for coordinate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coordinate) references an alternative spelling, **coördinate** which it explains is very rare, but helps explain its pronunciation.
The umlaut on the second 'o' is in this case called a [diæresis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diaeresis#English), a mark that is becoming much rarer (as are most forms of accentuation in English).

> (orthography) A diacritic ( ¨ ) placed over a vowel letter (especially the second of two consecutive ones) indicating that it is sounded separately, usually forming a distinct syllable, as in the English words naïve, Noël

As Wiktionary explains, *the dieresis is becoming increasingly rare in US English typography, so the spelling coordinate predominates*.

Comment: On page 503 of *Garner’s Modern English Usage*, Bryan Garner writes that “The phrase *✳increasingly less* is a jarring oxymoron that would be better rendered *less and less* or *decreasing*...In fact, *increasingly* is a word that aspiring stylists might do well to jettison from their vocabulary—or at least use less and less.”

Comment: Yes, come to think of it, **decreasingly** would be the best replacement.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a double vowel, in "coordinate," at least not like "wood."

The word used to be written "co-ordinate," meaning that the prefix, "co" was kept separate from the rest of the word.

"Modern" usage has blurred this distinction.

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose when it did become one word, the diæresis was added to preserve the original sound

Comment: The spelling is arbitrary; the sound **is** a doubled vowel, separated by a semivowel - /kə'wordənet/.

Comment: @JohnLawler A doubled vowel to me means the _same_ vowel repeated. I don't recognise your transcription—I've always said and heard /koʊˡɔɹdɨnət/—but as I say it, the two o’s represent different vowels, and while the grapheme is doubled, the sound is not. It's a diphthong followed by a monophthong, just like _go aboard_ or _how indeed_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Whether it's the same vowel is a dialectal matter. Phonetically, a diphthongized /o/ and a retroflexed /o/ can't be identical. However, in my American idiolect, /o/ and /ɔ/ are neutralized before /r/ (which is phonetically [ɹ] in my idiolect), so I represent them with the same phoneme for convenience, same as I represent [ɹ] by /r/. There does have to be a high back diphthong gesture between them, however, and I use /w/ for semivocalic /u/ or /ʊ/, when needed. But since all my tense vowels are diphthongized automatically, it's only necessary with a following vowel, as here.

Comment: @JohnLawler Ah, I’ve become so inured to seeing phonetics in slashes on here that I didn’t realise you were talking phonemes. But if you’re saying the two vowels are phonemically the same and your tense vowels are automatically diphthongised (except where they merge with their lax counterparts), then surely the semivowel here is automatic and purely phonetic, and you’d more accurately have phonemic /koˈordɨnet/ in your notation. (Additionally, would tense and lax not merge before vowels too in most dialects, meaning you might as well write /kɔˈɔrdɨnet/?)

Comment: One always uses the more common symbol to represent the phoneme, so even if I didn't want to emphasize the semivowel, I'd do it /ko'ordənet/. But, since phonemic representation is _sui generis_ to a fault already, I prefer to use it to emphasize the points I want emphasized. That's the purpose of any orthography, imo.